# I am loging in to facebook page while I am using react-facebook-login in react

Tags: reactjs, facebook, authentication, react-google-login

after integrating facebook login button in react app when I am clicking on it. A login form is opening in new tab after logging in the same page is redirected to facebook welcome page. Why this facebook welcome page is opening? I am using latest react version 18 although the given library supports 16 or below. Please suggest any solution to this. Similarly I am facing the problem with react-google-login library where I am getting getting popup closed as error. Although I have tried clearing cache and cookies but got no result.

Answer (score 0):

for login with google, old sign in with google library is being deprecated https://developers.googleblog.com/2021/08/gsi-jsweb-deprecation.html in favor of the new Google Service Identity SDK,

You can use [@react-oauth/google](https://github.com/MomenSherif/react-oauth) it uses the new SDK